# Switch current tab from notification in Google Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Am I missing something in the Chrome [tabs documentation](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html) or is there a way for an extension to change the currently active tab?

I have an extension which, once the tab has finished loading, pops up a notification and, if the loaded tab is not selected, offers the user the change to change it to selected. Or at least that's what I want it to do.

Reading the [notifications API](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/notifications.html) I don't see any mention of a way of accessing `chrome.tabs.get`, but there is `chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()`. Anyone have any idea on how to turn that into what I'm looking to do?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can make a tab selected with:

```
chrome.tabs.update(tabId, {highlighted: true});
```

Chrome API is available inside notification html, so you can call any `chrome.*` method you like.

Comment: Yep, that's the one! I was trying to do it with `.get` instead. Thanks!

Comment: It is deprecated since Chrome 33. Please use tabs.Tab.highlighted.

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#property-Tab-highlighted

Answer (score 5):

<s>Not sure, but could you try adding a content script in an inactive tab (or just in all tabs), then sending a request to a non-active tab (`sendRequest`)? The content script should execute `window.focus()`. Again, not sure whether this works.</s>

[Update](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-update) the inactive tab, and pass `{ selected: true }`. That should work, since it's listed as an available setting there.

Answer (score 5):

Use `active:true` to switch to tab/focus it, and `highlighted:true` to select one or many like when you wanna move them around.

Comment: `active:true` does not affect whether the window should be focused. If you use `active:true` you should also use [`windows.update`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#method-update), or at least check the window first.

Comment: Indeed, but I wanted to clarify the common confusion around the difference between active and highlightend, since at first glance they seem to do the same.