# Change Active Window (chrome.tabs)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, tabs

I've made an extension for `pandora.com` and when the user clicks the extension icon it opens a new tab with pandora.

When pandora is already open in a new tab and the user clicks the extension, the extension will not open a new tab but I would like it to instead change the active tab to the tab with pandora already open.

This is what I have so far in my `background` page:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    var found = false;
    chrome.tabs.query({}, function (tabs) {
        for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
            if (tabs[i].url.search("pandora.com") > -1){
                found= true; 
            }
        }
        if (found==false){
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,{file: "buy.js"});
        } else {
             // Changes active tab to the tab with pandora open
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You should use `indexOf` instead of `search`. `String#search` is for regex, your code implicitly creates a regex from the string unnecessarily. It shouldn't make a difference in the output, but it is more suitable for your use case (and slightly faster).

Comment: @FabrícioMatté thanks for the advice, but do you have any knowledge as to solve my main problem (changing active window)?

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7223911/1331430

Comment: possible duplicate of [Switch current tab from notification in Google Chrome extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223827/switch-current-tab-from-notification-in-google-chrome-extension)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

UPDATE- `chrome.tabs.update(tabId, {selected: true});` achieves what I needed. Here's the final code:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    var found = false;
    var tabId;
    chrome.tabs.query({}, function (tabs) {
        for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
            if (tabs[i].url.search("www.pandora.com/") > -1){
                found = true;
                tabId = tabs[i].id;
            }
        }
        if (found == false){
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,{file: "buy.js"});
        } else {
            chrome.tabs.update(tabId, {selected: true});
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I'd switch that `search` by `indexOf` before you get a regex syntax error but yeah.

Answer (score 11):

Seems like the `selected` property of the second argument of `chrome.tabs.update` has now been deprecated.

Using the `active` property is the new way to do it:

```
chrome.tabs.update(tabId, {active: true})
```

If the tab to be activated is in another window, you also need to change the active window to that window using `chrome.windows.update`:

```
chrome.windows.update(windowId, {focused: true}, (window) => {
  chrome.tabs.update(tabId, {active: true})
})
```